# Spinner Items are only black bars

Tags: android, spinner

This was my first app for android and i is an Note App.
But now i am encountering an problem with an spinner.

In one of my screens i have an `Spinner` with which the user could choose from the given categories.
The problem is now that there are the right amount of items in the spinner and notes get assigned to the right categories but instead of the category name there are only black bars in the spinner.

Maybe some of you have had the same problem or know how to deal with it.
Below is my code how i create and fill the spinner.

Spinner in `layout.xml`:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/note_cat_value_dd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/note_name_value_tf"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/note_name_value_tf"
    android:prompt="@string/note_spin_prompt"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Filling the spinner:

```
    Cursor cat = connect.query("category", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> options=new ArrayList<String>();
    cat_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.note_cat_value_dd);

    while(cat.moveToNext())
        options.add(cat.getString(1));      

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
    cat_spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And there is no other code that contains the spinner besides one time where i get the selected item with `"cat = cat_spin.getSelectedItem().toString();"`.

Comment: Sounds like you are writing black text on black background.

Comment: But i never set the background of the items nor did i change the textcolor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the drop_down_item layout too, Spinner uses two different layouts. One for collapsed spinner (spinner_simple_item), and one layout for each option in the dropdown list:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: ANd what should this layout contain?
Just an <ListView> in which i change the properties?
Or is it more complex?

Comment: The layout contains a TextView, is almost the same layout simple_spinner_item. But Spinner widget search for dropdown layout to create the views it will display on its expanded state. Just put the method I've told you, and the Spinner will append the ArrayString options you setted to it with the information.

Comment: Ok now the Spinner Items are larger but still are all black. :(

Comment: Copy the layouts to your app resources, and set manually both colors, avoid the android theme and check if that works.
Remember to use R.layout, because android.R.layout will keep using android resources